# How to exclude one set of words but include another in qregexp?

Tags: regex, qregexp

I am trying to exclude a group of words but include another group of words in a qregexp expression but I am currently having issues figuring this out.

Here are some of the things I tried (this example included all of the words):

```
(words|I|want|to|include)(?!the|ones|that|should|not|match)
```

So I tried this (which returned nothing):

```
^(words|I|want|to|include)(?:(?!the|ones|that|should|not|match).)*$
```

Am I missing something?

Edit: The reason why I need such an unusual regex (include/exclude) is because I want to search through a series of articles and filter the ones that have the included words in them but not if they also have the excluded words in them.

So for example if article A is:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
```

and article B is:

```
Vivamus fermentum semper porta.
```

Then a regex that includes `lorem` would filter article A but not B.  But if `ipsum` is a word that I'm excluding, I do not want article A to be filtered.

I considered doing a regex to filter out the articles with the words that I want and then run a second regex excluding articles from the first set that I do not want, but unfortunately the software I am using does not allow me to do this.  I can only run one regular expression.

Comment: That doesn't make sense. You're explicitly enumerating the words you want to match ("include"). There's no need to "exclude" anything afterwards; you already know what's on your whitelist.

Comment: What do you mean by include? at least one word from the list?

Comment: I use this RSS software (QuiteRSS) that allows me to filter out articles using qregexp that contain certain words.  However, I do not want the articles that contain these words to be filtered if the words in the negative lookahead are also in the article.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://xkcd.com/1313/ or http://nbviewer.ipython.org/url/norvig.com/ipython/xkcd1313.ipynb

Comment: All the answers are the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
^(?:(?!\b(?:the|ones|that|should|not|match)\b).)*\b(?:words|I|want|to|include)\b(?:(?!\b(?:the|ones|that|should|not|match)\b).)*$
```

You need to add lookahead to both parts after you find words whcih should match.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/bK9wF1/3

or

```
^(?!.*\b(?:the|ones|that|should|not|match)\b)(?=.*\b(?:words|I|want|to|include)\b).*$
```

Add both conditions under `lookaheads`.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/uF4oY4/60

Answer (score 4):

I think there is no need in a tempered greedy quantifier. Use excluded words as alternatives inside an **anchored negative look-ahead**. Let me guide you through this.

You say, you have `Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.`, and you want it to match since it contains the word `lorem`. The regex is `\\blorem\\b` (with *QRegExp.CaseInsensitive* set to `1`) where `\b` is used to force whole word matching. To prevent the match in case the string contains the word `ipsum`, you need to use the lookahead at the very beginning of the string.

```
^(?!.*\\bipsum\\b).*\\blorem\\b
```

Now, [it does not match the string in question](https://regex101.com/r/bK9wF1/2).

To add more alternatives, we can use an [alternation operator `|`](http://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html), and we can do it like this: `^(?!.*\\b(?:words|to|exclude)\\b).*\\b(?:words|to|include)\\b`. Note the use of [non-capturing groups](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3512471/non-capturing-group), it does not store any captured texts and potentially improves performance as compared to capturing groups that save the matched text in a buffer.

Thus, you get

```
^(?!.*\\b(?:the|ones|that|should|not|match)\\b).*\\b(?:words|I|want|to|include)\\b
```

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/bK9wF1/3)

Two remarks:

1. At the demo Web site, single backslashes must be used, I am doubling them here for the `QRegExp`.
2. In Qt, `.` in the pattern matches any character including a newline. At the demo Web site, the dot does not match newline symbols. You may want to replace it with `[^\n]` if you need the same functionality, but I think it is not necessary.

Answer (score 2):

You were so close. The reason

```
^(words|I|want|to|include)(?:(?!the|ones|that|should|not|match).)*$
```

doesn't work is because it means ***start*** with one of the words that I want to include and continue til the end with things, which are not one of the words that I don't want to include. To fix it, you can simply change the starting check to use positive lookahead:

```
^(?=.*(?:words|I|want|to|include))(?:(?!the|ones|that|should|not|match).)*$
```

Now this means ***ensure*** that **from the beginning til some point**, there is at least one of the words that I want to include and then continue as in the original regex.

To make it even more strict, you could use [word boundaries](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html):

```
^(?=.*\b(?:words|I|want|to|include)\b)(?:(?!\b(?:the|ones|that|should|not|match)\b).)*$
```

**Note** that these are all case sensitive. To change that, you can use [`QRegExp::setCaseSensitivity`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qregexp.html#setCaseSensitivity)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
^(?:(?:(?!\b(?:the|ones|that|should|not|match)\b).|))*?\b(?:words|I|want|to|include)\b(?:(?:(?!\b(?:the|ones|that|should|not|match)\b).|))*$
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

See [Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/IvKoW9RxfEDBmrjc) (with matching and non-matching examples).

*Note: The above assumes QRegExp supports variable-length lookahead - I haven't verified this.*

**Explanation:**

1. All words must be exact (e.g. include "word" but not "sword" or "words") so are wrapped in `\b` either side.
2. For the words you want to include it only matters that *at least one* of the appears *at least once* - so that is all that is being searched for in.
3. None of the words in the exclude list may appear **before or after** the searched for word, hence need an "exclusion group" either side of it.
4. Exclusion groups are implemented using a method that is explained very well in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/406230/regular-expression-to-match-line-that-doesnt-contain-a-word#406408).
5. The first exclusion group uses `*?` to make it non-greedy so it doesn't consume the whole text and stops as soon as the searched for word is found.
6. The regular expression is wrapped in `^`...`$` to ensure the whole string is checked/matched, not just part of it.
7. All groups are marked as non-capturing groups by using `?:` immediately after the first parenthesis.
8. The matching should presumably be case insensitive so the regular expression should have the appropriate flag to do this (e.g. /i).

Answer (score 0):

A simplified version of what you seem to need:

`^(?:(?!ipsum).)*(?:lorem)(?:(?!ipsum).)*$`

[Formatted:](http://www.regexformat.com)

```
^                    # BOS
 (?:
      (?! ipsum )          # Preceding text, but not these words
      . 
 )*
 (?: lorem )          # Text wanted
 (?:
      (?! ipsum )          # Following text, but not these words
      . 
 )*
 $                    # EOS
```